# How to run my ruby on rails website on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2

I have my rails 5 website on an AWS server, everything works fine for me but i need to change region due to problems with sending emails, i created an image of my instance using the information [in this web page](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/administration/change-region/) and then i executed it specifying the new region but when i tried to access through the ipv4 address the page stays loading and doesn't show me my website that worked well in the other instance, i tried to access through the console using the key pair and all the files from my previous instance are there. my server uses nginx. what could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to access the old IP address. When you moved the instance to a new region it will get a new IP address.

Another possibility is that the web server on the server was not started automatically. You may have to configure that to start on boot. The procedure may depend on how you set up the server.

Comment: no, I'm accessing the Public DNS (IPv4) with which I access with the console key pair, but it still doesn't show me the page, It should see my site because when I restart my old instance it shows me the website automatically, I restarted nginx and it still doesn't show in my new instance